# change AjaxFileUpload text button

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

is there any way to change text buttons from an ajaxFileupload example:
"Select file"
"remove"
"pending"
"upload"
"uploaded"

change these texts to a custom text? 
im using asp.net c# and the last ajaxtoolkit library
any idea will be helpul. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following, Run `AjaxFileUpload_change_text()` function after page load (i.e. on `Document.ready`). Here jQuery has been used.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () {
         AjaxFileUpload_change_text();

     });

     function AjaxFileUpload_change_text() {
         Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_SelectFile = "Select File";
         Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_DropFiles = "Drop files here";
         Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Pending = "pending";
         Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Remove = "Remove";
         Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Upload = "Upload";
         Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Uploaded = "Uploaded";
         Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_UploadedPercentage = "uploaded {0} %";
         Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Uploading = "Uploading";
         Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_FileInQueue = "{0} file(s) in queue.";
         Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_AllFilesUploaded = "All Files Uploaded.";
         Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_FileList = "List of Uploaded files:";
         Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_SelectFileToUpload = "Please select file(s) to upload.";
         Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Cancelling = "Cancelling...";
         Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_UploadError = "An Error occured during file upload.";
         Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_CancellingUpload = "Cancelling upload...";
         Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_UploadingInputFile = "Uploading file: {0}.";
         Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Cancel = "Cancel";
         Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Canceled = "cancelled";
         Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_UploadCanceled = "File upload cancelled";
         Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_DefaultError = "File upload error";
         Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_UploadingHtml5File = "Uploading file: {0} of size {1} bytes.";
         Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_error = "error";
     }

</script>
```

Comment: Lol. Hope so. If it doesn't then you can manually change texts like following:
`$('.ajax__fileupload_selectFileButton'.text('My Select File Text'));`
You will need to find out similar class names for other things you want to change.

Comment: I could not test your code, because I'm having trouble rendering the ajaxuploadfile maybe you know why it looks like this? [images link](http://i49.tinypic.com/292y2oz.png)

Comment: Is it happening with or without using my suggested change?

Comment: No. I think it was because i was using scriptmanager.registerstartupscript and i was having troubles with a javascript function. so i decided to stop using it. Thank you anyway

Comment: i got that error with ajaxtoolkit script manager but it doesnt happen with asp:scriptmanager